# Unable to use Graphviz library in Python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, graphviz, flowchart

Here is the code I try to execute:

```
from graphviz import Graph 

# Instantiate a new Graph object
dot = Graph('Data Science Process', format='png')

# Add nodes
dot.node('A', 'Get Data')
dot.node('B', 'Clean, Prepare, & Manipulate Data')
dot.node('C', 'Train Model')
dot.node('D', 'Test Data')
dot.node('E', 'Improve')

# Connect these nodes
dot.edges(['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE'])

# Save chart
#dot.render('data_science_flowchart', view=True)
```

The `render` function won't work, and I have not idea what is wrong. If commented out, the code works, but of course produces nothing. My goal is to make a visualization of the graph (PNG image, or PDF file). Just trying to plot a rudimentary flowchart in Python, I am open to using other libraries than graphviz: I am new to this, and tried graphviz after reading recommendations, tested a dozen scripts posted online, but none of them work, always resulting in the same error.

Here is the error:

```
$ py graph2.py
py graph2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 81, in run_check
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vince\graph2.py", line 17, in <module>
    dot.render('data_science_flowchart', view=True)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\rendering.py", line 122, in render
    rendered = self._render(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\rendering.py", line 324, in render
    execute.run_check(cmd,
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 84, in run_check
    raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd) from e
graphviz.backend.execute.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute WindowsPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Comment: I tried with networkx instead of graphviz, and I am able to plot flowcharts with networkx.

Comment: Does C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py exist?

Comment: My guess is that this is the source of the problem. I was surprised to see many examples (for beginners) that I have no doubt must be working, but somehow do not on my system. Nowhere it is mentioned anything about execute.py. Now I am really a beginner, maybe I am missing a basic thing that everybody knows.

Comment: No need to guess.  Check existence of file.  If not, then find out how to install it.  https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/

Comment: @ravenspoint I don't think the `execute.py` file is missing because the traceback contains the path to it.

Comment: Do you have path to  `dot.exe` file in your [system's or user's PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/)? You can fastcheck this by running `dot -V` at  command line, this should show version number if `dot.exe` is in `PATH`. To use the [`graphviz 0.20.1`](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) python's library, you must also install the original [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/) software by following [this tutorial](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#installation).

Comment: I did not know it was this involved to install GraphViz. Thank you for the info. In the end, I used NetworkX (it did not rquire extra steps besides the standard pip install).